# LINQ query forms

Tags: c#, linq

I often see linq queries written in either of these forms:

Form #1:

```
from t1 in table1 
where t1.SomeField == "Something"
select t1.FieldName
```

Form #2:

```
table1.Where(c=> c.SomeField == "Something").Select(n=> new {n.FieldName})
```

- What is the difference between these two forms of Linq queries?
- Is there any difference in performance ?
- Also when I search for Linq query tutorials I always get results for
  the first form, if I want to learn the syntax for the second Linq
  form below, what keyword to use for the search?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: The first one is just a language extension, it will be transformed into the second one during compilation. So there's no performance difference. The second form uses the LINQ `extension methods`. Maybe that's what you're looking for as a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The second one is with the short lambda expression
2. No, the second one however is faster to write.
3. Use lamba expression to find it.

The first version is a bit easyer to read according to many.
However lambda is faster to write, and personally I think it's just as clear as the first one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

The first one is called `query expression` and second one is called `lambda expression`, They are equivalent. Two syntax will compile to exactly the same code. The compiler changes the query expression into the equivalent Lambda expression before compiling it, so the generated IL is exactly the same.
**One more thing**:
Chained lambdas are much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The first form uses query syntax and the second form is called lambda expressions. There is no difference in performance, nevertheless the second form relies on generic delegates which gives you more flexibility to plug-in the expression from external layers, or pass them as method parameters.

refer to : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx
for more info.

Search for LINQ lambda expressions.

Comment: How is the lambda version more flexible? The difference is in the way its written. You can also name the tables with the first method in order to link up

Comment: @PieterSchool can you plugin in an expression to the `where` clause in the query syntax ? you can do that in lambda.

Comment: jou can by naming the used 'object' like you would in sql and reffering to the named variable to conduct a where statement. Takes a lot longer to code, but it is possible.

Comment: @PieterSchool i would appreciate if you can add an example i would love see it as i have never seen this before. But to support my point, you mention that it "Takes a lot longer to code" which kinda supports my argument that lambdas are more flexible.

Comment: @PieterSchool I would appreciate it too.

Comment: @SirajMansour This is what you reffered to right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662406/dynamic-expressions-in-where-clause-linq-to-sql

Comment: @PieterSchool exactly, you can pass the Expresison<> predicate, or the Func<>

Answer (score -2):

Form # 2 is the actual c# form.

Form # 1 just adds a syntatic sugar and query format for Form # 2.

I prefer Form # 2 as it is aligned well with c# code.

Comment: By actual c# form, i mean it follows c# syntax, query form has special syntax.